# Oauth2 and Microservices

Tags: oauth-2.0, microservices

Throughout this afternoon, I tried to implement a micro service architecture without success. The great problem is the security. I read the Oauth2 doesn't work with Spring cloud unless your implementation uses the api getaway like a Oauth2 client. I have tried this solution, the api gateway do login in the Oauth2 but the access to the business services don't recognize the Oauth2 login of the api gateway.

I follow the example at https://github.com/piomin/sample-spring-oauth2-microservices

Can someone say me what is wrong in the example?

Comment: `access to the business services don't recognize the Oauth2 login` could you please elaborate what you mean by that?

Comment: I try a envirotment with 5 microservices: 1 GateWay, 1 Oauth2 Server, 1 Eureka register and 2 bussines service (Client service and Fares services). when I try to access a client service rest url the client service ask for login, this service doesnt get the login I have done in gateway service